# How to get the id of a button inside a viewCell

Tags: c, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a button inside a viewCell and I have two paid and canceled states that appears in this Label Text = "{Binding statusDescr}", when the state on the label is paid the button should appear and when it is canceled the button should not appear. My problem is that I can not get the ID of the button inside a viewcell to make it visible when the status on the label is paid and invisible when it is canceled

```
<ListView x:Name="Lista"  
          SeparatorColor="Gray" 
          SeparatorVisibility="Default" 
          HasUnevenRows="True" 
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Bindenter code hereing entityName}" 
                                       TextColor="White" 
                                       Font="14"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding cmPaymentDate}" 
                                       TextColor="White" 
                                       Font="14"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding statusDescr}" 
                                       TextColor="White"
                                       Font="14"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                <Button x:Name="cmdOpen" 
                                        Text="Open pdf" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding paymentAmount}" 
                                       TextColor="White"
                                       Font="14" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="End" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding paymentNumber}" 
                                       TextColor="White" 
                                       Font="10" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="End" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like an excellent place to bind the `IsVisible` property of the button to the paid state:

```
<Button x:Name="cmdOpen" 
        IsVisible="{Binding paidState}" 
        Text="Open pdf" />
```

Note that this will only work if the paidState property is a bool. If your just using something like a double to store the remaining amount, you'll need to use a [converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) to change the value into a bool. Your XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:DoubleToBoolConverter x:Key="doubleToBool" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<!--your code --->

<Button x:Name="cmdOpen" 
        IsVisible="{Binding amountRemaining, Converter={StaticResource doubleToBool}}" 
        Text="Open pdf" />
```

And then the converter:

```
public class DoubleToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
               object value, 
               Type targetType, 
               object parameter, 
               CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value == 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
               object value, 
               Type targetType, 
               object parameter, 
               CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: But this paid or canceled status will appear on a label @Felix D.

Comment: So it's a string? The Converter approach is still valid it would be `return (string)value == "Paid";` or whatever the Paid string is. I would recommend using an Enum instead of strings though to prevent "magic strings" from floating around, but that's another topic

Comment: Yes, it´s. But I still understand how I can  to get id button in code behind, my listview Is to be populated from an API. I should check if the status on the label is paid should the button appear btn.IsVisible = true, it's being a little hard to figure out why I'm still new to Xamarin!! @Andrew

Comment: @AmaroManungu but there is no need to do this kind of things in code behind. Check out [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm) and [DataBindings in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) - **If you are new to Xamarin this is something you really should look at !**

Comment: @FelixD. I've been testing the MVVM but I had a lot of difficulty to implement these last days